# memory execution in large php program execution

Tags: php

I have created script where I get user review from Yelp, google etc using their API.

Using this review for Part of speech tagging, kinda Natural lang processing stuff.

I keep loop, which contiously keep fetching the review and extract noun, adjective for each.

I am using this tutorial:

http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging

When I execute the script, it abruptly stops after 40-50 review processing. It does not show any error. DOes is it due to

"`php has run out of space in memory`"

as per one of the comment on above link. OR some other issue. When I tried my script with limited review example, it works fine.

Here is the link where I execute my script:

http://ec2-54-186-110-98.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/scrap/getreview.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your script -

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: can you please tell me whether above issue is due to memory limit or what

Comment: Since you are running a script that is consuming too much of your server memory. So according to the docs, -1 means there is no memory limit. You can read more here http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when i fetched some mediumtext column from mysql. Are you using like this?

Comment: In above case I display data without mysql, but same scenario takes place when I store and fetch data from mysql, could you get rid of it?

Comment: Are you fetching all images from database?

Comment: No, I am storing tweets into table and displaying same by fetcing them